# How to update to kde 4.14.1?

Tags: 14.04, kde

I have Ubuntu 14.04. I installed Kde using:

```
sudo apt-get install kde-full
```

That provided me with kde Platform Version 4.13.3
How can i update it to 4.14.1?

Thanks

Edit: A terminal command would be very helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add Kubuntu Backports PPA

Open terminal and type

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:kubuntu-ppa/backports
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

It should upgrade yor kde  version to 4.14